# I have a react js page with 5 components inside. I want to change the text contents by clicking a button. How can I do it?

Tags: reactjs, dom

How can I change text contents by clicking a button in my react js page?

I planned to categorize the contents, but I have 5 separated components inside i don't know how to make it simpler

This is my root js code

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import '../../../translation/index'
import Benefit from './benefit.component'
import Partners from './partners.component'
import SeoContent from './seo.component'

function FinanceProductLanding () {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Benefit />
            <Partners />
            <SeoContent />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render( <FinanceProductLanding/>, document.getElementById('finance-product') )
```

Each components contains of 2 categories contents, one will appeared if I clicked 'this' button, then the content should be changed if I clicked 'that' button. 
Currently the page built with angularjs, I used document.getElementById() to change the texts. how could I do the same thing with react js?

Comment: hello, please tell us everything you tried so far, and also some information with codes may help us to understand what the problem really is and what kind of solution you need.

Comment: I have updated the question, thank you in advance @ronydavid

Comment: so, you want to change the text inside the content or the content itself?

Comment: the content itself @ronydavid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your explanation i thought all you want to do is hide or unhide component by clicking buttons. i tried to achieve it like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xf4pia), please let me know if you need something less or more

Comment: thank you so much. that's exactly what I want with an addition that inside each components, I have contents that I need to show inside component 1, and contents that should show inside component 2

Comment: it is not edited yet, and I dont really get it, do you mean that u want to transfer/send component1 content to component2 ?

Comment: ok, I get it now,  I already update my answer , please check it

Answer (score 0):

Add state for the component that contains those 5 components. The click event changes the state and text contents will change.

```
+----------+
| Top Comp | state: { text: '' }
+----------+
     |
     |         +--------------+
     +---------| Display Comp | <label>{ this.state.text }</label>
     |         +--------------+
     |
+----------+
|  Button  | onClick() => this.setState({ text: 'Your text' })
+----------+
```